# im trying to print off the errors in one sheet on another but cant quite figure out how

Tags: google-sheets

So the data is sensitive so i cant give a link on here to it but heres the basics

## **Details**

for the data im having trouble with atm:

```
column range = K:QR
row range  = 3:98  is where the main data is
row range = 99:196 is filled with function that check for errors in rows 3:98
```

Starting with K the columns are paired off one being for students the other being for tutors and the docs purpose is to take attendance.(Example:   K3:K98 has student info and L3:L98 has tutor info)

in K99 i have this formula

```
=if(
   or(
     {
       and(K3 = "MRT", isblank(L3)),
       and(K3 = "MST", isblank(L3)),
       and(K3 = "RT", isblank(L3)),
       and(K3 = "ST", isblank(L3)),
       and(istext(L3), isblank(K3))
     }
   ),
   $B3 & " " & $C3,
   ""
 )
```

this looks for an error in the the cells K3 and L3 then if it finds one prints the students name in the cell

In L99 theres the same exact formula except it outputs the date instead of the name if it finds an error

Ive copied K99 and L99 and pasted it through K99:QR:196 which should bassically do this for every cell pair int he doc that i need to (i know i need to adjust the ranges im planning on working on that later)

All i need to do now is look through K99:QR:196 and see if my functions found any errors and if so take that information and combine it all in to one row on another sheet removing any blank cells but i cant seem to figure this part out

## **Edit**

I forgot to mention everything in K3:QR98 is data validated. The student column has different codes like if the student was absent or if they had a substitute tutor or things like that and the tutor cells just have a drop down list of all the tutors. So I would only need information in the tutor column if the cell next to it in the student column says they actually worked with some sort of tutor. Thats what the formula i made does it checks if the student cells have one of those codes that indicates they worked with a tutor then there needs to be information in that tutor column otherwise the tutor column would be empty if the student didn't work with anyone. It also checks to see if theres information in the tutor column but not in the student in case someone was inputing the data and forgot to put the student information and just put the tutor

## **Side Note**

I've only posted on stack overflow a few times and the time before last my scope was too broad and got a lot of downvotes so if theres any errors or context that needs to be changed to fit posting standards please let me know in the comments what or how it needs to be changed and ill make the changes to fit accordingly.
(also i tried putting 4 spaces for the code but for some reason after 2 it goes down)

Comment: You might consider a redesign. Google Sheets offer some nice "array" formulas which can really simplify things like this - for example `=FILTER($K$3:$K$98, $L$3:$L$98="", $K$3:$K98<>"")` will print all values in `K3:K98` into separate rows where there is a blank value in `L3:L98` and some value in `K3:K98`.

Comment: there actually isnt any actual data yet its all "potential" data (im hoping to use this next year for my organization) but a breakdown further of whats put up top is:
k3:k98 is data validated with codes for whats going on with the student normally it would be "RT" for regular tutor but sometimes they do makeup sessions or have different tutors and there are different codes for that.
In L3:L98 its just a dropdown list of the tutors to pick from if the student worked with a tutor so it wont always be filled

Comment: and K99 and L99 both check the K3 and L3 pairs to look for errors and K prints the student name if it finds one and L prints the date if it finds one and i just extended that function down so K and L 100 both do the same checks for K and L 4 all the way through K and L 98 then repeating down to QQ and QR columns

Answer (score 0):

JOIN/SPLIT combo would help:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(K99:QR196&""),"")))
```